# Create and style a div element with HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a text field and button that reads a width and height of a quadrilateral. You enter the width and height, click the button, then a quad appears with those specifications. For some reason I can't get Javascript to read a measurement correctly, so nothing happens.

Here's what I have:

```
    <html>
    <style>
    </style>
    <head>
    <title>Make a Polygon!</title> 
    <script language="javascript">
       // var element = document.createElement('div');
       // element.className = "someID";

        function func(form) {
            var element = document.createElement('div');
            element.className = "someID";
        var wide = form.width.value;
        document.body.appendChild(element); 

        // this properties work//
        var a = document.getElementsByClassName('someID');

            for(var i in a ){
                a[i].style.zIndex='3';
                a[i].style.color='rgb(255,255,0)';
                a[i].style.background='rgb(0,102,153)';
            //a[i].style.width=wide;
            a[i].style.width='70px';
                a[i].style.height='200px';
                a[i].style.left='500px';
                a[i].style.top='90px';
            }  
        }
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <form name="widthForm" method="get"> Width: 
    <input type="text" name="width" value=""> <p> 
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Create" onclick="func(this.form)"> 
    </form>

    <br>

    </body>

    </html>
```

So far I'm testing the width only.

It's partially based on code found here:
[How to Set the Left and Top CSS Positioning of a DIV Element Dynamically Using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649778/how-to-create-div-element-dinamically-and-add-cusing-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You're submitting the page, and instantly refreshing it.  Change the submit element to just a button :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `submit` to `button`, and add `return false` statement to limit the button submits form when click, because if do that, the page will be refreshed and div added in javascript could not be seen. Try this:

```
<html>
    <style>
    </style>
    <head>
    <title>Make a Polygon!</title> 
    <script language="javascript">
       // var element = document.createElement('div');
       // element.className = "someID";

        function func(form) {
            var element = document.createElement('div');
            element.className = "someID";
        var wide = form.width.value;
        var height = form.height.value;
        document.body.appendChild(element); 

        // this properties work//
        var a = document.getElementsByClassName('someID');

            for(var i in a ){
                a[i].style.zIndex='3';
                a[i].style.color='rgb(255,255,0)';
                a[i].style.background='rgb(0,102,153)';
            //a[i].style.width=wide;
            a[i].style.width=wide;
                a[i].style.height=height;
                a[i].style.left='500px';
                a[i].style.top='90px';
            }  

        }
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <form name="widthForm" method="get"> 
    Width: 
    <input type="text" name="width" value=""> 
    Height:
    <input type="text" name="height" value=""> 
    <br>
    <p> 
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Create" onclick="func(this.form);return false;"> 
    <!--         ^^^^^^                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^-->
    </form>

    <br>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please **explain** the solution (and problem, if necessary), don't just post code. Also, are you playing the "spot-the-difference" game? What exactly did you change in the code?

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for reminding me:), I forgot to explain for my changing in the code, I am sorry for that.